# how to select all inside IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a IBOutletCollection property and action for button1 to button9.  Each and every button is pressed color will change,

```
-(IBAction)btnCollectionAction:(id)sender {
   counter = 0;
   btnSelecter = sender;

   if (counter == 0) {
      [btnSelecter setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      counter = 1;
   }
   else  {
      [btnSelecter setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      counter = 0;
   }

}
```

IBOutlet for selectall button,

```
- (IBAction)selectButtonFunction1:(id)sender {

     if (counter == 0) {
       [selBtn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       counter = 1;
     }
     else  {
       [selBtn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       counter = 0;
     }

}
```

the above both script works well.

My question is -  if i pressed the select all button (change to whiteColor), the above all nine button must change to whiteColor else blackColor.

I tried like this:

```
if(selBtn1.touchInside) {
    [btnSelecter setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
else {
    [btnSelecter setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

it will change only one button instead of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last part of your question is vague, I didn't understand the last portion. From your title I understand that you need to get all the `UIButton` from `IBOutletCollection`. I'm answering for that question.

You can toggle the color like:

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(id)sender
 {
    for (UIButton *button in buttonCollection)
    {
       if([button titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor blackColor]])
       {
          [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
       else
       {
          [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Shankar: what you want actually ? do you want to change all button color to white or black ? Or do you want to change the color of selected button to white and all others to black ?

Comment: i want to toggle that color when button is pressed

Comment: i want to get title which button is pressed and display it on another buttons title.  Is this possible!

Comment: @Shankar: yes possible, you can use the sender parameter for this. just debug and check the content of sender parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: 
1. Create `IBOutletCollection` with all your buttons (You Allready done this)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *myButtons;
```

2. Iterate throughout collection to configure target and appearence for each button:

```
   for (UIButton *button in self.myButtons)
    {
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];  
    // Do any additional configuration here
    }
```

3. Add target to `selectAll` button and assign Tag property for selectAll button

```
[selecAllButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
selectAllButton.tag = 10000; // you can other tag number
```

4. Create `buttonPressed:` Handler

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
 {
   if(sender.tag = 10000) 
   {
     for (UIButton *button in self.menuButtons) {
       if([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
           button.selected = YES;
        }
      }
    } else 
    {
      // handle other button actions  
    } 
 }
```