# Change button title

Tags: ios, objective-c

i created nine buttons using IBOutletCollection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367504/how-to-select-all-inside-iboutletcollection]).

My question is - i want to get title which button is pressed and display it on another buttons title. Is this possible!

Comment: Yes this is possible. What have you tried? What did not work for you? Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)btn {

    yourNextVCobject.buttonTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",btn.titleLabel.text];


    // then push to ur vc.
}
```

In your Next VC,

In `.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *buttonTitle;
```

In `.m`

```
[yourAnotherBtn setTitle:self.buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: button is present on another view controller not in same view controller.  what to do now!

Comment: just create button as property in another view controller and access it by using another view controller object..mm

Comment: can you show some example because i'm new to objective c

Comment: in button action r u pushing to next vc?

Comment: yes i pushed vc in storyboard

Comment: Do like my edited answer, if you ok with this accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to set the title of clicked button to targetted another button.

```
-(IBAction)clickbutton:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *firstButton = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSString *neededtitle = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@",firstButton.currentTitle];
   [anotherbutton setTitle:neededtitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```